# Android View options - draw to a canvas directly or use views

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm converting a project that I wrote in AIR a long time ago to native Android.  In AIR, positioning views was fairly easy in x,y coordinate systems.  With native Android though, I am trying to approach this in a correct way, but I'm unsure how to approach.

My view will consist of two circles in the background, with small objects within those circles that can roll around.  There will be another view drawn on top of the circles to make it seem like there is glass over the circle, entrapping the small objects.  The small objects are bound to the background circles.

I guess what I'm really asking is canvas drawing the best approach here, or is a view-based layout workable as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your best option would be to use a `SurfaceView`.  This is basically a hardware accelerated canvas.  On of the benefits is that you can overlay standard widgets over top of it if you need to so you can mix and match custom and standard components.  [Here is a link](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/05/drawing-on-surfaceview.html) to a website that walks you through getting a `SurfaceView` up and running

Comment: I was waiting to see if I got some other opinions, but I've already started coding this with a surface view and I like it!  Thanks for the suggestion :D